# What outermost block scope of A::N::f the Standard is talking about in the example at §3.4.1/6

Tags: c++, c++11, name-lookup

Example at 3.4.1/6

```
namespace A {
   namespace N {
      void f();
   }
}
void A::N::f() {
   i = 5;
   // The following scopes are searched for a declaration of i:
   // 1) outermost block scope of A::N::f, before the use of i
   // 2) scope of namespace N
   // 3) scope of namespace A
   // 4) global scope, before the definition of A::N::f
}
```

The [following code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e2a647f48f05698) is based on this example. Note that it prints 1. If I comment out `i = 1;` it prints 2. If I then comment out `i = 2;` it prints 3, which gives the idea that whatever this outermost block scope of A::N::f is, if you define `i` on this scope, the name `i` will be found before the others by the compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
    int i = 2;
    namespace N {
        int i = 1;    
        void f();
    }
}


int i = 3;
void A::N::f() {
    std::cout << i << '\n';;
    // The following scopes are searched for a declaration of i:
    // 1) outermost block scope of A::N::f, before the use of i
    // 2) scope of namespace N
    // 3) scope of namespace A
    // 4) global scope, before the definition of A::N::f
}

int main()
{
    A::N::f();
}
```

Comment: So? Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 4):

The phrase isn't used elsewhere in the standard, but we can safely conclude that it's referring to the outermost block scope *within that function*. That is, the function body's scope. This is perfectly intuitive and unsurprising.

**It means that a local variable with the name `i` is sought out first.**